# Why is Laravel 5.7 pagination not showing more pages after the first page result

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I intend to paginate a laravel eloquent model using a where clause. I expect the page links to show and be clickable leading to the clicked page. This is the default controller in which I paginate without a where clause.

```
 public function index(Request $request){

  $users = User::paginate(12)->onEachSide(1);           
  return view('/**',compact('users'));
}
```

I am able to paginate through till the last page. This is the route (I have placed the name is asterisks for confidentiality.:

```
Route::get('/**', 'SearchController@index');
```

This functions better, however I try to limit the rows with a where clause:

```
  public function search(Request $request){

$location = $request->location;
$talent  = $request ->talent;

$users = User::where('talent',$talent)->where('location',$location)->paginate(12);

return view('/searchResult',compact('users');    
  }
```

This is the route:

```
Route::get('/**', 'SearchController@search');
```

However, in the second case, the pagination result returns blank when I try to navigate. I am not sure why this is happening.
On the front view, I have:

```
              {{$users->links()}}
```

Comment: What code are you using to render the pagination links within the view?

Comment: {{$users->links()}}

Comment: Assuming that `$location` and `$talent` come from the query string, you need to use `{{$users->withQueryString()->links()}}` in order for those query parameters to be passed to the next page

Comment: Apologies that only works in Laravel 7+. Instead do `{{ $users->appends(Request::except('page'))->links() }}` for Laravel 5.

Comment: Alright I'll try this and get back to you once I'm in my environment. I couldn't find much in the docs though.

Comment: It works, I have updated the answer and hopefully it will be useful to some others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works and I am now able to paginate effectively. Answer by lufc in the comment though. However, I am curious about the mechanism.

```
     {{ $users->appends(Request::except('page'))->links() }}
```

Comment: By default, the pagination links created by `links()` do not append the existing query string. So if you had a page with `mypage?location=USA`, then the pagination link created would show `mypage?page=2` and would cut off the location on page 2. The `appends()` function adds parameters to a URL. In this case it is appending the entire existing query string `except()` any page numbers added by the pagination (otherwise on page three you would get `mypage?location=USA&page=2&page=3`.

Comment: Kindly upvote your answer. Could you please share a link to any description of further details available on the laravel docs or any others?

Comment: Thanks lufc for the answer! It has been helpful